# Add a BitmapImage to Project Images Folder in C#

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, tiles

In my application on certain events I retrieve a `BitmapImage`, but I would like to apply this image to the primary tile.

My only problem is that the `BitmapImage` isn't in the Images folder within my project, so I can't load it onto the primary tile.

Can someone show me code on how to do this?

Feel free to add any additional information on stuff that I missed.

Comment: You can load an image from anywhere in your project or `IsolatedStorage` - what have you tried? please show your attempts.

Comment: I need to put the bitmap image in the local folder? Not save it to IsolatedStorage, as ShellTile only accepts images from a Uri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy the image to the folder `Shared/ShellContent/` in the Isolated Storage of your app. From there you can reference to it via an Uri with the "isostore:/" scheme that you give it to the primary tile.

For example:

```
tile.BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/" + myCoolImageThatIWantToShow, UriKind.Absolute);
```

Comment: Should I just save the image in the normal fashion to IsolatedStorage or differently?

Comment: Not sure what you mean "normal fasion" in this context, but I would say yes. If you don't need the image elsewhere in your app, you can even save it directly to that folder. It's simply that the image you are trying to show in your primary tile must be located in that folder.